# Why is my CPU clock speed low and how can I increase my CPU speed and performance?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, performance

Whenever my CPU is under high or full load, the CPU clock speed drops below the base frequency. `htop` during high load:

[image: htop]

I'm on a Dell Inspiron 15 5510 with an i7-11390H

`neofetch` output:

[image: neofetch output]

I have ensured that I am in "Performance" mode in Ubuntu and am plugged in to a proper wattage power supply and am not thermal throttling (CPU temps shown in `htop` above)

How can I increase my clock speed to its boost frequency and thus improve performance?

Comment: sensor reads can sometimes be misleading. if you boot it from a cold state, and leave it idle for a bit, what readings do you get? are they in or close to the 35-45C range?

Comment: @Mokubai I don't believe it's something else in the system overheating as under similar conditions, the CPU is able to run at much higher clock speeds (up to 3.2GHz) where is then thermal throttles as the CPU temperature reaches from 85C to 99C, also according to ThrottleStop Windows, the reason was CPU thermals and not PROCHOT.

Comment: @Mokubai I still tried disabling `PROCHOT` in Ubuntu but got the error `wrmsr: pwrite: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @FrankThomas If I boot from a cold state in a cool environment, it stays around room temp, 40-45C